# mysql count items in group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-concat

I am having a trouble with using GROUP_CONCAT in MySQL
My tables `g0` as follows:

```
ID  Age Sex
-------------
1   16  Male
2   18  Female
3   16  Male
4   18  Female
5   16  Male
```

But I need the table to look like

```
ID        count
1,3,5       3
2,4         2
```

I tried this query:

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
CONCAT(cnt)) cnts FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(ID) as cnt FROM g0  GROUP BY Age , Sex order by ID Desc) ;
```

But I get this error message:

```
1248. Every derived table must have it's own alias
```

Answer (score 11):

There's no need to have the `count` inside `group_concat` - just select it as a different item with the same `group by` expression:

```
SELECT   GROUP_CONCAT(id), COUNT(*)
FROM     g0
GROUP BY age, sex
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```